# Hyperlink in Jupyter Notebook in IBM Watson Studio - Refused to Connect

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ibm-watson

I tried adding a Hyperlink in My Jupyter Notebook at IBM Watson Studios. Its working while editing Notebook in Studio itself but When I am sharing the link of My Jyp. Nb. its not working properly. Its trying to load the page but says "Refused to connect". I tried Links of Google, Stack overflow etc. however link of website "practicepython.org" is working. I want to know Whats happening here?

[Link for Jyp Nb (links are at last Cell in Nb)](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/af53612b-e863-4bac-bc56-ff11ce391c39/view?access_token=77b000ad4edac1bacbec8a3dd24c40f31281b00dff08a23875fb788ab1ba3c4a)

Comment: I would assume your notebook is not trusted. None of the links work unless I right click on them and open that way.

Comment: Its in Trusted mode.